NavigationException thrown while navigating from Static Server Render to Interactvie Server Render Components
I have a scenario where Users can log in directly via URL without Submitting a form on the Static Server Component in the Blazor Server App.
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync() {
  try {
    if (HttpMethods.IsGet(HttpContext.Request.Method))
      await HttpContext.SignOutAsync();

    if (parameter && condition) {
      await DirectLogin();
    }
  } catch (Exception ex) {
    _logger.LogError(message: ex.Message);
  }
}

async Task DirectLogin() {
  try {
  //Perform some logic here and then SignIn

    await HttpContext.SignInAsync(principal, new AuthenticationProperties {
      ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(5)
    });

    _navigation.NavigateTo($"/direct/page/{parameter}", true);
    //Here I get this exception "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.NavigationException"

  } catch (Exception ex) {
    errorMessage = $ "Error: {ex.Message}";
    _logger.LogError(message: ex.Message);
  }
}

This login Component is in a Static Server Render mode whereas after the successful SignIn, the User will be redirected to an Interactive Server Component.
But _navigation.NavigateTo is throwing the following exception

Exception of type
'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.NavigationException' was thrown

I know this is a known issue and folks on Github are suggesting not to catch this exception as it is handled internally.
But apart from that I don't know the real reason why this exception is occurring.
